# PHP - How to send request to web sites?

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl, I am wondering how would I send post/submit data on my page to those websites? The web site has "host, time, port". My MYSQL database has a list of urls. I was thinking of `curl_multi` but I am not sure.

Please someone post examples. It has to be a fast method.

Basically feteches the url and post.

```
while($resultSet = mysql_fetch_array($SQL)){                
    $ch = curl_init($resultSet['url'] . $fullcurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);           
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
}
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your question. Is it about sending POST data (which I answered), or about sending multiple requests?

Comment: Sending $host, $time, $port to multiple urls in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how to do it with curl_multi. Although you should break it up so you only have a certain amount of URLs going out at once (i.e. 30). I added the follow location directive, which you usually want.

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$ch = array();
while($resultSet = mysql_fetch_array($SQL)){                
    $ch[$i] = curl_init($resultSet['url'] . $fullcurl);
    curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
}
$running = null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh,$running);
} while ($running > 0);
$num = count($ch);
for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++ ) {
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
}
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Comment: May I ask, What is these part for? "curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);" "curl_multi_exec($mh,$running);
} while ($running > 0);
$num = count($ch);
for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++ ) {
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
"

Comment: Also, "curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);" I research and found this "usleep(100000);" what does they do? Please add comments on the code.

Answer (score 1):

[The PHP cURL reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) says that the `CURLOPT_POST` option, set to `true`, makes it a POST request. `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` sets the fields that you will send in `foo=bar&spam=eggs` format (which one can build from an array with `http_build_query`).

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'foo=bar&spam=eggs');
```

Comment: I already have something similar "$fullcurl = "?host="$fullcurl = "?here=".$here."&cash=".$cash."&weet=".$weet;". Any more help?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
while ($resultSet = mysql_fetch_assoc($SQL)) {
  $ch = curl_init($resultSet['url']);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,2);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fullcurl);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close();
}
```

Comment: I have this on "$ch = curl_init($resultSet['url'] . $fullcurl);", what would be recommend to replace? Thne I have this coded "curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);"... Confused here. Needing some help again

Comment: don't add fullcurl to the url.. it is the postfields.  it should be in  key=value&key2=value2 format.. remove the question mark from the start of your $fullcurl and run my code.